# Data structure for multiple x-y data with additional meta information in PyQt5 app

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to find a better approach than my current one to manage the storage of my PyQt application. 
I have a QTreeWidget where I can add and delete rows. Clicking on these QTreeWidgetItems shows the data linked to it.
Each of that linked data consists of a graph with x-y values, and some additional metadata.
Currently in the `__init__` method I have two empty lists defined:

```py
self.xData = []
self.yData = []
```

When I load data the x and y values are np.ndarray type, and they get appended to `self.xData` and `self.yData`. The metadata is written to a dictionary, the key is the index of the data, value is the metadata. Later I access all of them by index.
I've tried to use dictionary the following way:
in `__init__`:

```py
self._dict = {}
```

The keys were the current index of the row, value is the (x, y) tuple (pseudocode):

```
self._dict['index of the row'] = (x_values, y_values)
```

I think this is still not an elegant way of dealing with the data.

There is the code you can try, but I had to disable and delete huge amount of functionality (including metadata) to reduce its length and to clean it up.

**logic.py**

```py
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView, QFileDialog, QTreeWidgetItem

from ui import Ui_SPP

class SPPWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_SPP):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SPPWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.xData = []
        self.yData = []
        self.treeWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.loadButton.clicked.connect(self.loadData)
        self.treeWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.previewData)

    def previewData(self):
        """ Function to update the plot."""
        curr = self.treeWidget.currentIndex().row()
        if curr == -1:
            pass
        else:
            Ydata = self.yData[curr]
            Xdata = self.xData[curr]
            self.widget.canvas.axes.clear()
            self.widget.canvas.axes.plot(Xdata, Ydata, 'r')
            self.widget.canvas.axes.grid()
            self.widget.canvas.draw()


    def loadData(self):
        """ Function to load file into QTreeWidget"""
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,"Load interferogram", "","All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)", options=options)
        try:
            if fileName:
                x, y = np.loadtxt(fileName, unpack=True, delimiter=',', usecols=(0, 1))
                self.xData.append(x)
                self.yData.append(y)
                l1 = QTreeWidgetItem([fileName.split('/')[-1]])
                self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(l1)
            self.previewData()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = SPPWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ui.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import numpy as np
from plotwidget import PlotWidget


class Ui_SPP(object):
    def setupUi(self, SPP):
        SPP.setObjectName("SPP")
        SPP.resize(1302, 832)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SPP)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.GDSPP = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.GDSPP.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.GDSPP.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.GDSPP.setObjectName("GDSPP")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.GDSPP)
        self.GDDSPP = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.GDDSPP.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.GDDSPP.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.GDDSPP.setObjectName("GDDSPP")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.GDDSPP)
        self.TODSPP = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.TODSPP.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.TODSPP.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.TODSPP.setObjectName("TODSPP")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.TODSPP)
        self.FODSPP = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.FODSPP.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.FODSPP.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.FODSPP.setObjectName("FODSPP")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.FODSPP)
        self.QODSPP = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.QODSPP.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.QODSPP.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.QODSPP.setObjectName("QODSPP")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.QODSPP)
        self.messageBox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.messageBox.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.messageBox.setReadOnly(True)
        self.messageBox.setObjectName("messageBox")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.messageBox)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3, 1, 3, 2, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.delayLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.delayLine.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.delayLine.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.delayLine.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.delayLine.setObjectName("delayLine")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.delayLine)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.SPP1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.SPP1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.SPP1.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.SPP1.setText("")
        self.SPP1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.SPP1.setObjectName("SPP1")
        self.SPP1.setStyleSheet("""QLineEdit { color: blue }""")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.SPP1)
        self.SPP2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.SPP2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.SPP2.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.SPP2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.SPP2.setObjectName("SPP2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.SPP2)
        self.SPP3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.SPP3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.SPP3.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.SPP3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.SPP3.setObjectName("SPP3")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.SPP3)
        self.SPP4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.SPP4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.SPP4.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.SPP4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.SPP4.setObjectName("SPP4")
        self.SPP2.setStyleSheet("""QLineEdit { color: orange }""")
        self.SPP3.setStyleSheet("""QLineEdit { color: green }""")
        self.SPP4.setStyleSheet("""QLineEdit { color: purple }""")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.SPP4)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4, 1, 1, 2, 1)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.loadButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.loadButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 30))
        self.loadButton.setObjectName("loadButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.loadButton)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeWidget.setExpandsOnDoubleClick(False)
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setFont(0, font)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidget)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 3, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.widget = PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 450))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 1, 1, 3)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.spp_ref = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.spp_ref.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.spp_ref.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.spp_ref.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spp_ref.setObjectName("spp_ref")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.spp_ref)
        self.fitOrderLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.fitOrderLine.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.fitOrderLine.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.fitOrderLine.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.fitOrderLine.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(651651, 16777215))
        self.fitOrderLine.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.fitOrderLine.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.fitOrderLine.setObjectName("fitOrderLine")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.fitOrderLine)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_8)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 30))
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        SPP.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(SPP)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1302, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        SPP.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(SPP)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        SPP.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(SPP)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SPP)

    def retranslateUi(self, SPP):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        SPP.setWindowTitle(_translate("SPP", "SPP Panel"))
        self.GDSPP.setPlaceholderText(_translate("SPP", "GD "))
        self.GDDSPP.setPlaceholderText(_translate("SPP", "GDD"))
        self.TODSPP.setPlaceholderText(_translate("SPP", "TOD"))
        self.FODSPP.setPlaceholderText(_translate("SPP", "FOD"))
        self.QODSPP.setPlaceholderText(_translate("SPP", "QOD"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.treeWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.delayLine.setPlaceholderText(_translate("SPP", "delay (fs)"))
        self.SPP1.setPlaceholderText(_translate("SPP", "SPP1"))
        self.SPP2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("SPP", "SPP2"))
        self.SPP3.setPlaceholderText(_translate("SPP", "SPP3"))
        self.SPP4.setPlaceholderText(_translate("SPP", "SPP4"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("SPP", "Set SPP\'s"))
        self.loadButton.setText(_translate("SPP", "Load item"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("SPP", "Delete item"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("SPP", "Loaded files"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("SPP", "Clickable SPP"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("SPP", "Stop clicks"))
        self.spp_ref.setPlaceholderText(_translate("SPP", "Reference point"))
        self.fitOrderLine.setPlaceholderText(_translate("SPP", "Fit order "))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("SPP", "Reset all"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("SPP", "Fit and report"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    SPP = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_SPP()
    ui.setupUi(SPP)
    SPP.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**plotwidget.py**

```py
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout

class PlotWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)
```

My question mainly aims at finding a better data structure, but every little improvement is appreciated.
Note that I intentionally didn't follow PEP8 there, because PyQt's naming convention is against that, and I'd rather keep the code coherent.
Basically you can load any x-y dataset from a txt file which looks like this:

```
1,1
2,4
3,9
4,16
..
```

[Here is an example dataset you can load.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-YKFM9zPdG-ABR5kTpV4zyA6UyrXPOV3/view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have worked a lot with PyQt, but in most GUI libraries tree-view-items have facilities to store *userdata*. For `QTreeWidgetItem` you can use the `data` and `setData` methods. It might conflict with the MVC-pattern but practicality beats purity.

My revised `logic.py` with `self.xData` and `self.yData` removed and data stored in the GUI objects:

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView, QFileDialog, QTreeWidgetItem

from ui import Ui_SPP

class SPPWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_SPP):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SPPWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.treeWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.loadButton.clicked.connect(self.loadData)
        self.treeWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.previewData)

    def previewData(self):
        """ Function to update the plot."""
        curr = self.treeWidget.currentItem()
        if curr:
            stuff = curr.data(0, QTreeWidgetItem.UserType)
            print(stuff['name'])
            print(stuff['meta'])
            self.widget.canvas.axes.clear()
            self.widget.canvas.axes.plot(stuff['Xdata'], stuff['Ydata'], 'r')
            self.widget.canvas.axes.grid()
            self.widget.canvas.draw()


    def loadData(self):
        """ Function to load file into QTreeWidget"""
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,"Load interferogram", "","All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)", options=options)
        try:
            if fileName:
                x, y = np.loadtxt(fileName, unpack=True, delimiter=',', usecols=(0, 1))
                name = fileName.split('/')[-1]
                l1 = QTreeWidgetItem([name])
                stuff = {
                    'Xdata'  : x,
                    'Ydata'  : y,
                    'name'   : name,
                    'meta'   : 'other data',
                }
                l1.setData(0, QTreeWidgetItem.UserType, stuff)
                self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(l1)
            self.previewData()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = SPPWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This seems interesting. Do you know how well it behaves when you load a bigger amount of data? (Approx. 50-60 QTreeWidgetItem)

Comment: @Péter Leéh No I don't, but I don't expect problems, widely used (gui) libraries tend to be good.